# Editing AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to edit the AMPScript from the below. However, I could not figure out a way to make changes to this code. Is it something to be done with permissions?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you are trying to Edit "Template-based Email",if you directly click on CODE VIEW without clicking on any content BLOCK within email, the code will be locked as below.
[image]
 so if you want to edit the HTML code of any block first you must CLICK ON THE BLOCK as below, then you will be able to edit the code.

[image]

Comment: This is only a partial truth - i will include a answer regarding the difference between template and email later, This week

Comment: Thank you Vishal .. that helped. I really needed to just edit the block as you've mentioned.